# Jackson JSON field mapping capitalization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm not clear how jackson deals with capitalization in mapping fields. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

```
{"user":{"username":"user@host.com","password":"pwd","sendercompid":"COMPID","service":{"host":"address","port":6666,"service":"S1","serviceAsString":"s1"}},"MDReqID":"ghost30022","NoRelatedSym":1,"Symbol":["GOOG"],"MarketDepth":"0","NoMDEntryTypes":3,"MDEntryType":["0","1","2"],"SubscriptionRequestType":"1","AggregatedBook":"N"}:
```

Above is my json, below is my exception...

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "MDReqID" (class com.myco.qa.fixrest.MarketDataRequest), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: , "mdreqID", "marketDepth", "user", "subscriptionRequestType", "aggregatedBook", "mdentryType", "symbol", "mdupdateType", "noRelatedSym", "noMDEntryTypes"])
```

Above is my exception, below is my class...

```
public class MarketDataRequest {
    private User user;
    private String MDReqID;
    private char SubscriptionRequestType;
    private int MarketDepth;
    private int MDUpdateType;
    private char AggregatedBook;
    private int NoMDEntryTypes;
    private ArrayList<Character> MDEntryType;
    private int NoRelatedSym;
    private ArrayList<String> Symbol;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getMDReqID() {
        return MDReqID;
    }

    public void setMDReqID(String MDReqID) {
        this.MDReqID = MDReqID;
    }

    public char getSubscriptionRequestType() {
        return SubscriptionRequestType;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionRequestType(char subscriptionRequestType) {
        SubscriptionRequestType = subscriptionRequestType;
    }
```

... et cetera

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Since your setter method is named `setMDReqID(…)` Jackson assumes the variable is named `mDReqID` because of the Java *naming conventions* (variables should start with lower case letters).

If you really want a capital letter use the [*@JsonProperty*](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation on the *setter* (or - for serialization - on the *getter*) like this:

```
@JsonProperty("MDReqID")
public void setMDReqID(String MDReqID) {
    this.MDReqID = MDReqID;
}
```

Comment: You wrote "mDReqID " but jackson needs "10 known properties: , mdreqID". All lower why? Im facing same problem, JsonProperty fix it, but why all chars are lower not only first as you mentioned?

Comment: Is there a way to deserialize object correctly, when there is no access to class (it is a dependency)?

Answer (score 53):

You can also do

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
```

on the class to capitalise all property names in the JSON message

Comment: we don't want to do on all properties only on 1

Comment: In case that it doesn't work for you just out of the box, remember about setting JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() in your ObjectMapper. In my case I needed to set a pair of introspectors - my custom one and this jackson one.

Comment: try `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy.class)` if you can't find `UpperCamelCaseStrategy`, it's from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy`

Comment: Documentation says: `PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class` is deprecated. "Since 2.12 use `PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy` instead(see: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2715 for reason for deprecation)"

Answer (score 21):

Add `@JsonProperty` on the setter that matches the property name in your received JSON string:

```
@JsonProperty("MDReqID")
public void setMDReqID(String MDReqID) {
    this.MDReqID = MDReqID;
}
```

Additionally add `@JsonProperty` annotation to the *getter* as well for your output to appear in the *conventional* format:

```
@JsonProperty("mDReqID")
public String getMDReqID() {
    return MDReqID;
}
```

Now you can name your variable whatever you like:

```
private String mdReqID;
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by:

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    static class UserInfo {
        //@JsonProperty("UUID")
        private String UUID = "11";
        private String UserName = "22";
        private String userName = "33";
        private String user_Name = "44";
        private String user_name = "55";
        private String User_name = "66";
        private boolean HasDeleted=true;
        private boolean hasDeleted=true;
        private boolean has_Deleted=true;
        private boolean has_deleted=true;
        private boolean HAS_DELETED=true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new UserInfo());
        System.out.println(s);


        UserInfo userInfo = objectMapper.readValue(s, UserInfo.class);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userInfo));
    }
```

output:

```json
{"UUID":"11","UserName":"22","userName":"33","user_Name":"44","user_name":"55","User_name":"66","HasDeleted":true,"hasDeleted":true,"has_Deleted":true,"has_deleted":true,"HAS_DELETED":true}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JsonNaming Annotation to get all Class Field Names in Proper Case

Use lombok.Data Annotation to automatically make it work without adding getters and setters in your class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies;

import lombok.Data;

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
@Data
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem , after have try `UpperCamelCaseStrategy` but still this error occurred , the strategy made my field `pContent` to ObjectMapper property `Pcontent`, as not want to add @JsonProperty for every field, simply use `gson` instead at last