# json jackson capital after number

Tags: json, xml, groovy, jackson

I am having trouble with the capitalization conversion of json to xml in a camel route on "zip2ndPart". Everything was working fine when I was creating elements, but then I realized the user wanted attributes.

If I do

```
@XmlElement
String zip2ndPart
```

it works fine. However,

```
@XmlAttribute
String zip2ndPart
```

is capitalizing the "N" after the "2". I've tried adding a setter with no luck. Quite new to json, and a bit perplexed.

Also tried @JsonProperty('zip2ndPart') per several other answers, e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303110/jackson-json-field-mapping-capitalization`, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Being new to the mapping, I was somehow thinking I needed to use the @JsonProperty, but it was of course the @XmlAttribute(name = 'zip2ndPart').