# Stop Jackson from changing case of variable names

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am using Jackson in Spring to serialize my class to JSON. When I serialize a class like the example below, Jackson is changing the names of certain fields from Camel Case to lower case. I know I can work around this by creating custom (de)serializers, yet I am hoping to turn this off globally. Perhaps by setting a property in application.properties.

Per the [default Jackson naming strategy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180928175452/http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html), this is not supposed to happen:

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, default Java property naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is...

```
class Foo {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String aName;
    private final String name;
    private final String abName;

    Foo(final String firstName, final String aName, final String name, final String abName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.aName = aName;
        this.name = name;
        this.abName = abName;
    }
    // Getters here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Foo foo  = new Foo("first", "a", "name", "ab");
        final String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);
}
```

**Expected:**

{"firstName":"first","name":"name","abName":"ab","**aName**":"a"}

**Actual:**

{"firstName":"first","name":"name","abName":"ab","**aname**":"a"}

**EDIT:**

Narrowed the problem down to interpretation of the getters. Starting to look like a bug in Jackson.

```
class Foo {
    private final String aName;

    Foo(final String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return this.aName;
    }
}
```

Serializes to `{"aName":"a"}`

However,

```
class Foo {
    private final String aName;

    Foo(final String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public String getAName() {
        return this.aName;
    }
}
```

Serializes to `{"aname":"a"}`

Comment: use `@JsonProperty("AName")` and you are done

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem here is more about [JavaBeans(TM) Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). According to the spec (page 58)

> However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we
>   check if the **first two characters** of the name are both upper case and
>   if so leave it alone
>
> “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
>
> “Z” becomes “z”
>
> “URL” becomes “URL”

And you have an edge case with `aName` field . Because if the getter looks like `AName()` , then when you convert back from this getter you should look for `AName` field **according to the specification**. Here is additional info [explanation](https://dertompson.com/2013/04/29/java-bean-getterssetters/)

So to fix this, you can use a proper getter(`getaName()`) or `@JsonProperty("aName")` annotation above field/getter

Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207335/1032167)

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem if you're using a class which is out of your control? i.e. from a third party jar where I cant edit the class.

Comment: @Mick I think you can try [jackson mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) or even custom deserializer( dont think there is any other way

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm not sure why Jackson reads `getAName` to `aname`, it's possible to force a Jackson to use a certain name with `@JsonProperty("AName")`. For example:

```
class Foo {
    private final String aName;

    Foo(final String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("AName")
    public String getAName() {
        return this.aName;
    }
}
```

(Got this solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303110/jackson-json-field-mapping-capitalization) closely related question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PropertyNamingStrategy option in Objectmapper.

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
```

Comment: For me, this strategy changes ISOCountryCode to IsocountryCode

Comment: latest version will be: `objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);`