# Spring Boot Open Api - case insensitive?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I have the following problem:

I have an endpoint with request body like ContactRequest:

```
public class ContactRequest{
  private String message;
  private Object result;
}
```

BUT this endpoint is invoked by some other service with JSON payload with upper case:

```
{
  "Message": "Some text",
  "Result": "Resultsdsddwd"
}
```

I try to use pattern in openapi.yml but I think it's not the correct fix for my problem because in code I use ContactRequest object with lower case fields...

```
 ContactRequest:
      pattern: ^[A-Za-z\s_-]+$
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - status
        - message
```

My endpoint:

```
public CommandResponse save(
       ContactRequest contactRequest){
...
}
```

Did someone have similar problem? I can't change the request body

PS.
Maybe there is something like @JsonAlias in OpenApi.yml generator file?

**UPDATE**
Maybe should I use global settings to set case insensitive?

My build.gradle file:

```
implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.6'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [Jackson JSON field mapping capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15303110/113116)?

Comment: @Helen I dont thnk so unfortunately...I can;t modify a class that is generated by openapi.yaml generation file

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this solution if it works in your case:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseStrategy.class)
public class ContactRequest{
  private String message;
  private Object result;
}
```

Built-in strategies are: KEBAB_CASE, LOWER_CASE, SNAKE_CASE, UPPER_CAMEL_CASE

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations

Comment: Yes but ContactRequest objet is generated by openapi so I can change this object only by openapi.yaml generation file