# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Symbol"

Tags: java, json, jackson, ebean

I am trying to take some JSON that looks like this (from AlphaVantage):

```
{
    "Symbol": "IBM",
    "AssetType": "Common Stock",
    "Name": "International Business Machines Corporation",
... more properties
}
```

And parse it using Jackson (& Ebeans):

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = response.body().string();
  Stock stock = objectMapper.readValue(json, Stock.class);
  stock.save();
```

My Stock class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends Model {

@Id
private Long id;
private String Symbol;
private String AssetType;
private String Name;
... other properties

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return this.Symbol;
}
public void setSymbol(String Symbol) {
    this.Symbol = Symbol;
}

... other setters/getters

}
```

Instead I am getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Symbol" (class com.myprojectname.Stock), not marked as ignorable (60 known properties: "ebitda", "sharesOutstanding", "bookValue", ....more fields
```

Why is Jackson having a problem connecting to my Stock class? How do I connect Symbol from the JSON into Symbol in the Stock class?

EDIT: I get the same error message if I change symbol to lowercase:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends Model {

@Id
private Long id;
private String symbol;

public String getSymbol() {
    return this.symbol;
 }
public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson JSON field mapping capitalization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303110/jackson-json-field-mapping-capitalization)

Comment: It's definitely setting me on the right path, but when I change Symbol to symbol in my Stock class variable, I am still getting: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Symbol"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the name of the property from `Symbol` to `symbol` won't help since we still have the `"Symbol"` in the json file.

You can try to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation [like in the example](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#1-jsonproperty). For the `"Symbol"` json field it can look like this:

```java
//...
    private String Symbol;

    @JsonProperty("Symbol")
    public String getSymbol() {
        return this.Symbol;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Symbol")
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.Symbol = symbol;
    }
// ...
```

This approach should also work for other fields which differ from the json counterpart by the uppercase / lowercase letter.

edit: Just like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303228/4880379) from the question linked in my comment above - paraphrasing it:

> Since your setter method is named `setSymbol()` Jackson assumes the
> variable is named `symbol` because of the Java naming conventions
> (variables should start with lower case letters).

edit(2): Other option would be leveraging [the object mapper configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#1-configuring-serialization-or-deserialization-feature). So instead of the annotations approach you could use the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36767648/4880379) and make the mapper case insensitive:

```java
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Other property I find useful is:

```java
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

described in the Baeldung's article linked above

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your `ObjectMapper` to check only fields and ignore getters:

```
JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .visibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .build();
```

- [How to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)