# How to Send this kind of Json Response

Tags: java, spring, rest

How To Send the Kind of api response when i am sending then the first letter become small
I want response key VehicleNumber but i am getting vehicleNumber
the First letter small i ma getting

````
    "status": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "VehicleNumber": "DL1ZD1455",
            "Address": "gurgaon sector 48,sector 48, gurgaon",
            "Latitude": 28.42682,
            "Longitude": 77.03228,
            "Alerttime": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "Speed": "21.000",
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success"
}```


i am getting this kind of response
````

{
"status": "1",
"data": [
{
"address": "Lucknow Airport Terminal,Uttar Pradesh",
"vehicleNumber": "DL1PD3231",
"speed": "0",
"latitude": 26.76383,
"longitude": 80.88558,
"alerttime": "2021-12-19 17:16:41"
}
],
"message": "Success"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson JSON field mapping capitalization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303110/jackson-json-field-mapping-capitalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Map> panicData = new ArrayList<Map>();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query1);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<Object, Object>hsa=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
                    String VehicleNumber=rs.getString(1);
                    String Address=rs.getString(2);
                    Double Latitude=rs.getDouble(3);
                    Double Longitude=rs.getDouble(4);
                    String Alerttime=rs.getString(5);
                    int spd=rs.getInt(6);
                    String Speed=spd+"";
                    hsa.put("VehicleNumber",VehicleNumber);
                    hsa.put("Address", Address);
                    hsa.put("Latitude", Latitude);
                    hsa.put("Longitude", Longitude);
                    hsa.put("Alerttime", Alerttime);
                    hsa.put("Speed",Speed);
                    
                    panicData.add(hsa);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy and override translate method and do something like this:

```
public static class UpperCaseJsonStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {
    @Override
    public String translate(String input) {
        return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }
}
```